# Is it possible to get two IMEI no's using cordova plugin if device has two SIM?

Tags: android, cordova, imei

I'm able to get one IMEI no from **cordova-plugin-android-imei** plugin, but I want to capture both(2) IMEI nos. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim go through this link get sim info separately object will return deviceid this may help you